# Why the output of c program is 40?

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
char *arr[] = { "sunbeam ","dac","wimc","pune","karad" };
char **ptr;
int i;
printf("size : %d\n",sizeof(arr));

}
```

this c program showing 40 as output please explain me how it comes.

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator BTW..`sizeof arr` will also do.

Comment: %zu instead of %d

Comment: In general case the output of this program is undefined, not "40". Using `%d` to `printf` the result of `sizeof` is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Two things: `arr` is an array of pointers, and `sizeof` returns the size in *bytes*.

Since `arr` is an array of five pointers to `char`, the result of `sizeof(arr)` is equal to `5 * sizeof(char *)`. Which on a typical 64-bit system (where pointers are 64 bits, i.e. 8 bytes) is `40` bytes.

Furthermore, you use the wrong format to print the result of `sizeof`. You should be using `"%zu"` (the `z` modifier because the argument is a `size_t`, the `u` type because it's unsigned). See e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for more information.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>

int main() {
   char *arr[] = { "sunbeam ","dac","wimc","pune","karad" };
   char **ptr =arr+2;
   printf("%s",++ptr[arr-ptr]-1);
  
   
   return 0;
} sir please can you explain me how this program will execute step by step

Comment: @MahendraShoor If you have another question, the *ask* another question. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Pointers will be size 2 on a 16-bit system, 4 on a 32-bit system, and 8 on a 64-bit system. 
Your code(Simplified for explanation) :

```
#include <stdio.h>   
int main() {
char*arr[] = { "a","b","c","d","e" };
char *arr1;
char **arr2;
 printf("Size of Array : %zu \n", sizeof(arr) );
 printf("Size of Array1 : %zu \n",sizeof(arr));
 printf("Size of Array2 : %zu \n",sizeof(arr));
 return 0;
 }
```

Output:

```
 main
 Size of Array : 40
 Size of Array1 : 8
 Size of Array2 : 8
```

Your program has nothing to do with the values inside array 
 `char *arr[] = { "a","the largest string in the array will still take 8 bytes","c","d","e" };` the pointer to array is a pointer to all those values,  takes 8 bytes for each index in 64 architecture. `sizeof(arr)` thus returns 40bytes for 5 elements .

Comment: no `cout` in C, so as a whole this is hardly a simplification.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I didnt pay attention on tag it was tagged in.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala is it acceptable now?

Comment: `%zu` is the proper formatting specifier for sizeof

Comment: Thanks, :) is zu for unsigned integers?